# Nuget Package works in console app but not in Web API app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I downloaded a package from Nuget Package. It's not a commonly used package, however the package works in a Console app, but does not work in a Web API app.

The console app and Web API are both running on .NET 5.0.

Can such situations occur? What could be the reason for this? I searched online but couldn't find a reason.

Note: the method in the package works fine in the console app, but when it runs in the Web API, there's no exception or anything; the method works fine and returns a status code of 200, it just returns the output as exactly what I input.

I did some research in the source code of the package I downloaded because it's a bit outdated. The package uses the `BinaryFormatter` class, and according to my research, this package is no longer supported by Microsoft.

However, I don't think this constitutes a problem because the package works fine in the console app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `I don't think this constitutes a problem` quite the opposite, it means the package is dead. .NET 5 is long out of support and shouldn't be used for any project, either new or old. It was never a long-term support version, something that was know before it was even released. Only even .NET versions are long-term support versions. BinaryFormatter isn't just out of support, actively being removed from the runtime because it's insecure and unfixable. Microsoft made that clear too

Comment: In short, stop using that package and stop targeting .NET 5. As for the official docs: [BinaryFormatter serialization methods are obsolete and prohibited in ASP.NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/serialization/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete) which say : `in ASP.NET Core 5.0 and later apps, they will throw a NotSupportedException` and `In .NET 7, the affected APIs are obsolete as error.`. The [.NET Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) shows .NET 5 reached End Of Support 2 years ago